# Words highlight when mouse is over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need some kind of help. How is it possible to highlight one word in my own paste text.

Like I have `<textarea></textarea>`, where I can paste text or just one sentence and when mouse is over one word it is being highlighted like here by Damovisa: http://jsfiddle.net/5gyRx/

```
<p>Each word will be wrapped in a span.</p>
<p>A second paragraph here.</p>
Word: <span id="word"></span>


// wrap words in spans
$('p').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.html($this.text().replace(/\b(\w+)\b/g, "<span>$1</span>"));
});

// bind to each span
$('p span').hover(
    function() { $('#word').text($(this).css('background-color','#ffff66').text()); },
    function() { $('#word').text(''); $(this).css('background-color',''); }
);
```

Regards

Comment: Maybe this will get you on the right track - http://www.strangeplanet.fr/work/jquery-highlighttextarea/ - It's only an emulated way of doing it, but as I see it, it should be possible to adapt the code to your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Man, you guys are fast !! - anyhow, as I made it ( was fun ) might as well share it

- yes Like Jonsuh answers well - here  using contenteditable

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/P7S3Q/1/**

Perhaps an addition here is **picking up on being able to paste/change text .**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wordscontainer" contenteditable="true">
    Paste words here ...
</div>

<div id="word"></div>
```

**JS**

```
function setHover() {
/* we could do to unbind here before re binding */
$('.wordscontainer span').hover(
    function() { 
        $('#word').text($(this).css('background-color','#ffff66').text()); },
    function() { 
         $('#word').text(''); $(this).css('background-color',''); }
);
}

$(".wordscontainer").keyup(function() {

    var $this = $(this);
    $this.html($this.text().replace(/\b(\w+)\b/g, "<span>$1</span>"));
    setHover();

});
```

**SOME CSS used for display/demo**

```
.wordscontainer { 
     padding:10px; margin:10px; 
     border:2px solid #999; min-height:400px;
 }
#word { padding:10px margin:10px; font-size:20px; }
```

Comment: wow, that is fantastic!!! 
Only one thing, when using chrome you cannot type your words :) the next letter jumps in front of typed one. with ie everything is super!

Comment: lots of room for improvement in this code, the whole contenteditable is fun to play with and can get more advanced with the document.exec commands. Hopefully this shows the start of something. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't if you look at what he does you will see that he wraps every word in a span tag. And then does what ever you need to.

The only way you could do this is if you took it out of the textarea, and wrapped it in a span tag. Similar to how things like tagit works.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do it with a `textarea` because of HTML tags.

However, you can use a `<div contenteditable="true">` to "simulate" a textarea.

### HTML

```
<div contenteditable="true">Each word will be wrapped in a span.</div>
<div contenteditable="true">A second paragraph here.</div>
Word: <span id="word"></span>
```

### JS

```
// wrap words in spans
$('div[contenteditable=true]').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.html($this.text().replace(/\b(\w+)\b/g, "<span>$1</span>"));
});

// bind to each span
$('div[contenteditable=true] span').hover(
    function() { $('#word').text($(this).css('background-color','#ffff66').text()); },
    function() { $('#word').text(''); $(this).css('background-color',''); }
);
```

### DEMO: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonsuh/F2NxT/)